# Trouble rendering Quake 3 maps

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, quake, bsp-tree

I've been working on a Quake 3 BSP loader. However I cannot get the faces to render correctly.

[image]

Here are the vertices for a map. Here's what happens when I render faces on a map.

[image]

This is the code for the render:

```
void bsp::render() 
{  
 for (    int j = 0; j <= bsp::lumps[13].length/sizeof(bspface); j++)//Read until end of lump
    {
     if ((bsp::faces[j].type == 1)||(bsp::faces[j].type == 3))       // 1=polygon, 2=patch, 3=mesh, 4=billboard    
       {        
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (    int k = 0; k <=  bsp::faces[j].numofverts - 1; k++)//Read until end of lump
           {
            glVertex3f(bsp::vertices[bsp::faces[j].vertexindex+k].position.x, bsp::vertices[bsp::faces[j].vertexindex+k].position.y, bsp::vertices[bsp::faces[j].vertexindex+k].position.z);
           }
        glEnd();    
       }
   }
}
```

Full source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                   
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <GL/GL.h>                                    
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <assert.h>                                   

using namespace std;

int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
int SCREEN_BPP = 24;
bool running = true;
bool lightmaps;
SDL_Event event;

#define MAX_BRUSHES     10000
#define MAX_FACES       10000
#define MAX_VERTS       10000000
#define MAX_TEXTURES    1000
#define MAX_LEAFFACES   65536

struct pos
{
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
};

struct bspface
{
 int   textureid;        // The index     into the texture array
 int   effect;           // The index for the effects (or -1 = n/a)
 int   type;             // 1=polygon, 2=patch, 3=mesh, 4=billboard
 int   vertexindex;      // The index     into this face's first vertex
 int   numofverts;       // The number of vertices for this face
 int   meshvertindex;    // The index     into the first meshvertex
 int   nummeshverts;     // The number of mesh vertices
 int   lightmapid;       // The texture index for the lightmap
 int   lmapcorner[2];    // The face's lightmap corner in the image
 int   lmapsize[2];      // The size of the lightmap section
 float lmappos[3];     // The 3D origin of lightmap.
 float lmapbitsets[2][3]; // The 3D space for s and t unit vectors.
 float vnormal[3];     // The face normal.
 int   size[2];          // The bezier patch dimensions.
};

struct bspvertex
{
 pos position;      //x y z
 float texturecoord[2];  //u, v texture coordinate
 float lightmapcoord[2]; //u, v lightmap coordinate
 float normal[3];        //x, y, z normalized vector
 char  color[4];         //RGBA color for the vertex
};

struct bsptexture 
{
 char name[64];      // The name of the texture w/o the extension
 int flags;          // The surface flags (unknown)
 int contents;       // The content flags (unknown)
};

struct bspbrush 
{
 int brushSide;           // The starting brush side for the brush
 int numofbrushsides;     // Number of brush sides for the brush
 int textureid;           // The texture index for the brush
};

struct bsplump
{
 int offset;
 int length;
};

class bsp
{
 public:
 ifstream    bspfile;
 bsplump     lumps[16];
 char        entities[10000];
 bspvertex   vertices[MAX_VERTS];
 bspface     faces[MAX_FACES];
 bsptexture  textures[MAX_TEXTURES];
 bspbrush    brushs[MAX_BRUSHES];
 int         faceindex[MAX_LEAFFACES];
 void load(string);
 void render();  
};

void bsp::load(string name)
{
 cout << "Loading BSP \"" << name << "\"" << endl;
 bsp::bspfile.open (name.c_str(), istream::binary);
 if(bsp::bspfile == NULL)
   cout << "ERROR: No file named \""<< name <<"\" found" << endl;
 else
     {
      char magic[64];                 //Number used in Quake 3 BSP header    
      bsp::bspfile.read(magic, 4);    //Read the magic number in the header of the BSP file it should be "IBSP"
      if((magic[0] != 'I')||(magic[1] != 'B')||(magic[2] != 'S')||(magic[3] != 'P'))
       { 
        cout << "ERROR: Not a valid Quake 3 BSP file" << endl;
       }
      else
          {
           int version;
          char vbuffer[4];                
          bsp::bspfile.read(vbuffer, 4);   
          for (    int k = 0; k <= 3; k++)    
             {
              ((char*)&version)[k] = vbuffer[k];
             }

          if(version != 46)//46 = 0x2e in hexidecimal
            cout << "ERROR: Unknown version of Quake 3 BSP" << endl;
          else
              {
               for (    int i = 0; i <= 16; i++)
                  {
                   char lumpoffset[4];
                   char lumplength[4];

                   //Read lumps offset
                   bsp::bspfile.read(lumpoffset, 4);                    
                   for (    int k = 0; k <= 3; k++)    
                      {
                       ((char*)&bsp::lumps[i].offset)[k] = lumpoffset[k];
                      }

                   //Read lumps length   
                   bsp::bspfile.read(lumplength, 4);                    
                   for (    int k = 0; k <= 3; k++)    
                      {
                       ((char*)&bsp::lumps[i].length)[k] = lumplength[k];
                      }

                   cout << "Lump " << i << " offset is " << bsp::lumps[i].offset << endl
                        << "Lump " << i << " length is " << bsp::lumps[i].length << endl << endl;                   
                 }

               //Load entities (LUMP 0)
               bsp::bspfile.seekg (bsp::lumps[0].offset, ios::beg);
               bsp::bspfile.read(bsp::entities, bsp::lumps[0].length);  

               //Load textures    (LUMP 1)            
               bsp::bspfile.seekg (bsp::lumps[1].offset, ios::beg);
               for (    int j = 0; j <= bsp::lumps[1].length/sizeof(bsptexture); j++) //Read until end of lump
                  {               
                   char buffer[72];           
                   bsp::bspfile.read(buffer, 72);  

                   for (    int k = 0; k <= 71; k++)//Read until end of lump
                      {
                       ((char*)&bsp::textures[j])[k] = buffer[k];
                      }
                  }

               //Load Leaffaces (LUMP 5)
               bsp::bspfile.seekg (bsp::lumps[5].offset, ios::beg);
               for (    int j = 0; j <= bsp::lumps[5].length/sizeof(bspvertex); j++) //Read until end of lump
                  {
                   char buffer[4];                 //create buffer for Leaffaces         
                   bsp::bspfile.read(buffer, 4);   //Read
                   for (    int k = 0; k <= 3; k++)    //Read until end of lump
                      {
                       ((char*)&bsp::faceindex[j])[k] = buffer[k];
                     }
                  }

               //Load vertices (LUMP 10)
               bsp::bspfile.seekg (bsp::lumps[10].offset, ios::beg); //Load vertex data from vertex lump (10)
               for (    int j = 0; j <= bsp::lumps[10].length/sizeof(bspvertex); j++)//Read until end of lump
                  {
                   char buffer[44];           //create buffer for verts    
                   bsp::bspfile.read(buffer, 44);   //Read
                   for (    int k = 0; k <= 43; k++)//Read until end of lump
                      {
                       ((char*)&bsp::vertices[j])[k] = buffer[k];
                      }
                  }

               //Load faces (LUMP 13)
               bsp::bspfile.seekg (bsp::lumps[13].offset, ios::beg); //Load face data from face lump (13)
               for (    int j = 0; j <= bsp::lumps[13].length/sizeof(bspface); j++)//Read until end of lump
                  {
                   char buffer[104];                 //create buffer for faces    
                   bsp::bspfile.read(buffer, 104);   //Read
                   for (    int k = 0; k <= 103; k++)    //Read until end of lump
                      {
                       ((char*)&bsp::faces[j])[k] = buffer[k];
                      }
                  }
                }
        }

    }
}
void bsp::render() 
{  
 for (    int j = 0; j <= bsp::lumps[13].length/sizeof(bspface); j++)//Read until end of lump
    {
     if ((bsp::faces[j].type == 1)||(bsp::faces[j].type == 3))       // 1=polygon, 2=patch, 3=mesh, 4=billboard    
       {        
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (    int k = 0; k <=  bsp::faces[j].numofverts - 1; k++)//Read until end of lump
           {
            glVertex3f(bsp::vertices[bsp::faces[j].vertexindex+k].position.x, bsp::vertices[bsp::faces[j].vertexindex+k].position.y, bsp::vertices[bsp::faces[j].vertexindex+k].position.z);
           }
        glEnd();    
       }
   }
}

bsp bspbuffer;

bool initGL()
{
 //Initialize Projection Matrix
 glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
 glLoadIdentity();
 //Initialize Modelview Matrix
 glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
 glLoadIdentity();
 //Initialize clear color
 glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );
 //glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
 return true;
}

float angle; 

void render() 
{
 angle = angle + 1;
 glPushMatrix();
 //Clear color buffer
 glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
 //Render quad
 glPointSize(5.0);
 glRotatef(angle,1,1,1);
 glScalef(.002,.002,.002);
 bspbuffer.render();
 //Update screen
 glPopMatrix();
 SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

 //While there are events to handle
 while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
      {
       if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
         {
          running = false;
          exit(0);
         }
      }       
 SDL_Delay( 1000 / 30 );
}

bool init()
{
 //Initialize SDL
 if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
   {
    return false;
   }
//Create Window
if( SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_OPENGL ) == NULL )
  {
   return false;
  }
//Initialize OpenGL
if( initGL() == false )
  {
   return false;
  }
 //Set caption
 SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL BSP", NULL );
 return true;
}

#undef main

int main()
{
 init();
 bspbuffer.load("test1.bsp");
 do
   {
    render();
   }while(running);   
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code indentation is horrible, and it's really hard to read and understand. You should try to follow a style, and align your code and comments. Also, I don't see why you're doing `for     int j [..]` everywhere.

Comment: The for functions are for loading arrays of characters in the memory address of a variable, Which works if you actually took the time and looked at the screenshots. The problem is with the rendering loop.

Comment: I think timms was wondering why you choose int j instead of int i - which is standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

The index you're using is pointing to the face polygon from the vertices lump. If you just want to see the map rendered you can try replacing GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP mode with GL_POLYGON.

The triangle version of that polygon is stored in the meshverts lump. So in order to render triangles you need indexes stored in the meshverts and offset from vertexindex of the face.

Answer (score 1):

For rendering both type 1 and type 3 faces, I recommend using GL_TRIANGLES with the meshverts in lump 11.  This is required for type 3 faces, but it works for type 1 also so you might as well use the same code for both.  In your loop on j, you'll want something like:

```
bspface *face = &bsp::faces[j];
int v = face->vertexindex;
int m = face->meshvertindex;
int n = face->nummeshverts;
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    bspvertex *vertex = &bsp::vertices[v + bsp::meshverts[m + i]];
    glVertex3f(vertex->position.x, vertex->position.y, vertex->position.z);
}
glEnd();
```

This of course presumes you add meshverts to your bsp class.

Meshverts are described as part of the [q3 map specs](http://www.mralligator.com/q3/), which I'm sure you've seen.